# Installing mongoose on node "require" undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongodb, no matter how install node and mongoose on ubuntu I can't get it to work. I always get the "require" not defined error

npm install mongoose
also tried npm install -g
and tried putting everything in one folder
mkdir node

Screenshot to show mongoose intalled in the node_modules

```
                    https://gamerholic/images/screenshot/mongoose.png test page where mongoose tries to connect 
   https://gamerholic/indexTest.php
```

'require' not defined message comes up

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose is meant to run from Node not in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a browser require (albeit a bit oddly) you can check out http://requirejs.org/

Comment: Mongoose has far too many dependencies that will not work in the browser for that.

Comment: And also, if you want to use NodeJS style require without all the wrapping craziness check out https://www.npmjs.org/package/browserify

Comment: Are you running this from the command line, ie `nodejs myfile.js` or are you trying to use this via html in a browser?

Comment: What im trying to do is connect node to mongodb withou exposing my db user and password... every blog... tip ive read says the samething... var blah =require ()

Comment: @user3052997 You are not going to be able to connect to mongodb from a browser.  That will only work in node.